# cluster failover generic application

Tags: cluster-computing, failover

Is there any way to monitor specific variables generated inside a generic application monitored by a failover cluster in windows server ?

I would like to avoid an internal application failure not being detected by the cluster monitoring...

Is there any way to supply the cluster monitor with specific application-generated statuses?